# Use of this.own() method in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

i would like to know the intention of the "this.own()" method in dojo widgets. This method is mentioned in the Dojo Api 1.8 Documentation, for example under diijit/form/button. I did not find anything that made sense to me on google. That is how the method is mentioned:

> **connect(obj, event, method)**
>
> Deprecated, will be removed in 2.0, use this.own(on(...)) or
>   this.own(aspect.after(...)) instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `own` function is defined in `dijit/Destroyable`, which is a base of `dijit/_WidgetBase` and thus most widgets.

> dijit/Destroyable is used to track handles of an instance, and then
>   destroy them when the instance is destroyed. The application must call
>   destroy() on the instance in order to release the handles

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Destroyable.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/Evented.html

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is: most of the things that you define inside `.own()` are getting correctly removed once the widget itself is destroyed. Using `.own()` prevents memory leaks in your app.

Answer (score 3):

> To remove a widget from a page, you can either call destroy or 
>   destroyRecursively on your widget.
>
> When you do that, anything that you added using this.own ( dojo/on, 
>   dojo/aspect, dojo/topic, dojo/router, the creation of a related DOM
>   node  or widget, etc.) will be removed and/or unregistered
>   automatically. This  is implemented via the dijit/Destroyable
>   interface.

[Understanding-WidgetBase-own-td4002453.html](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Understanding-WidgetBase-own-td4002453.html)
[Related Tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/understanding_widgetbase/)